formData.append on Radio Buttons doesn't carry checked value Ajax
I have this registration script where I am using AJAX to carry the inputted data over to PHP into a MySQL database. Everything works perfectly fine "EXCEPT" the value of the checked radio button. It only grabs the first value and not the value which was checked. Yes I am aware there are other jQuery methods that doesn't have this hiccup, however though I'm new to this, the form append Ajax method is going to be best for when uploading images and that's exactly what I will be using it for and will have many options using radio buttons along with the multi-upload image options. So I need to perfect this simple script before moving forward.
I've been searching high and low for two days now on the proper ways to collect radio button value data using the formdata.append line, no matter how I've modified this, it fails the script.
<script>
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
  _("mybtn").disabled = true;
  _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
  formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );

  formdata.append("input:radio[name=gender] :selected",_("Male").value);
    formdata.append("input:radio[name=gender] :selected",_("Female").value);
    formdata.append("input:radio[name=gender] :selected",_("Other").value);
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open( "POST", "register_script.php" );
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
    _("my_form").innerHTML = '<p style="margin:1em;background:#E33A29;color:#fff;padding:1em;border-radius:10px;">Thanks '+_("n").value+', you have succeessfully registered !.</p>';
      } else {
        _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        _("mybtn").disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;" method="post">
      <input id="n" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
      <input id="e" type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
      <span style="font-size: 18px;margin-top:0.5em;margin-bottom:1em;font-weight: bold;">Gender</span>
      <label>
            <input id="Male" value="Male" type="radio" name="gender"/>
            <span>Male</span>
        </label>
      <label>
            <input id="Female" value="Female" type="radio" name="gender"/>
            <span>Female</span>
        </label>
      <label>
            <input id="Other" value="Other" type="radio" name="gender"/>
            <span>Other</span>
        </label><br>
      <p><span id="status"></span></p>
      <BR>
      <button id="mybtn" type="submit" name="submit_mail" value="Register">Register</button>

    </form>
  </div>


Ids should be unique; you have two elements with the same id, "gender." I would recommend giving them a class of "gender" and using document.querySelector(".gender:checked") to retrieved the checked radio.

I tried the line you gave, even researched its uses and didn't work. it fails the script. I even tried  var gender = document.querySelector(".gender:checked").value; with each of the three inputs having the class of gender. still doesn't work.

How exactly did it fail the script? Is there an error message? What steps have you taken to debug it? Please [edit] your question to show your updates.

when I added the changes you spoke about, the form literally just refreshes itself. in the inspect window shows nothing. it just refreshes the form.

I changed all inputs for the radio button to have a class of ="gender" and tried adding a variable to this line you provided document.querySelector(".gender:checked") and when that didn't work I tried var gender = document.querySelector(".gender:checked").value;  and it still just refreshes the form .

I think you're selecting it correctly, but neglected to append it to your formdata. You may need to pass the submit event to submitForm() and call event.preventDefault() to prevent the form from submitting the traditional way. Also, an uncaught error could cause submitForm() to fail  and never reach return false;

I don't understand what all this meant but will research see if I get it and find a solution. thanks mate

formdata.append( "input:radio[name=gender] :selected", _("input:radio[name=gender] :selected").value );
tried this same result, not working

Is there an error message? Look at what the arguments for FormData.append() are supposed to be; you seem to be sending the element itself as the name parameter.

ok will research it some more. heading to work, so will tackle this a bit later.

no success YET...

Did you update your formdata.append() for the gender item? Please update your question to show your latests attempt(s).

yes updated. I tried   formdata.append( "input:radio[name=gender] :selected", _("input:radio[name=gender] :selected").value );
but still same result. not seeing anything else on formdata.append for radio buttons, they all don't carry the value

But did you research what arguments formdata.append takes? The first element is suposed to be the name of the argument; is "input:radio[name=gender] :selected" the name you want that item to have?

I got this error with script above.register.php?radio=on:187 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
at submitForm (register.php?radio=on:187:91)
at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (register.php:226:73)

You're calling _() with argument "input:radio[name=gender] :selected").value, which is meant to be an element id.; there are no elements with "input:radio[name=gender] :selected").value as the id.

ok this should be better,. I placed every radio button with their own id name and form data append to this   formdata.append("input:radio[name=gender] :selected",("Male").value);
formdata.append("input:radio[name=gender] :selected",("Female").value);
formdata.append("input:radio[name=gender] :selected",_("Other").value); and got this error instead register.php?radio=on:226 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/register_script.php".
submitForm @ register.php?radio=on:226
onsubmit @ register.php?radio=on:233 think I am on the right track here. "a bette error ;)"

It's not how I would have done it, but it seems to be letting you move on.

can you tell me what is wrong with this line?   ajax.send( formdata );
it's the only issue right now. I guess that line has to be modified to understand how to deal with the radio button elements value?

What is the problem with this line? the "error" posted above doesn't seem like it related to this. Or that it's an error at all.

register.php:226 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/register_script.php". that's the console output, however it doesn't submit the form data to my php script as It returns no responses. like if the email line doesn't have an @ it will return that the email is invalid. strange

That looks like a php error; have you searched the web for the error message?

I am as we speak. here is my php https://pastebin.com/78Ne9TDu which is pretty straight forward. don't see an issue with it.

you don't need to use ids on form elements, they are necessarily child elements of the form. ( ex: myForm.gender.value ).
This mechanism is  directly used with the FormData object.
sample code:


const myForm = document.querySelector('#my_form');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault(); // disable form submission (and page reload)
  
  // get data for your Ajax :
  let formInputs = Object.fromEntries( new FormData(myForm) );

  console.clear();
  console.log(formInputs);
  })
fieldset { width: fit-content; }
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form id="my_form" >
      <input name="n" type="text"  placeholder="Full Name" required>
      <input name="e" type="email" placeholder="Email"     required>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Gender</legend>
       <label>
          <input name="gender" value="Male" type="radio" required>
          <span>Male</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input name="gender" value="Female" type="radio" >
          <span>Female</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input name="gender" value="Other" type="radio"  >
          <span>Other</span>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <p><span id="status"></span></p>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" >Register</button>
      <button type="reset"  >clear</button>
    </form>
  </div>




neat, this works but it's a whole different ajax/jquery script from mine. why I am adamant about getting what I presented working, is because of a working multi image upload script I already have prepared, just need to add radio button data to it, that's my problem. I got a lot more to learn. thanks for the pointers mister jojo

@d-comet Actually it's rather your code that is "different", because I didn't invent this code, it corresponds to the standard way of processing html forms

@d-comet Also, use fetch() istead of your XMLHttpRequest(). I also thing you should prefefer to use a <dialog> element for your form.
